# JavaScript - How to put multiple LI into 1 UL using DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-lists

I'm trying to put multiple `li` into 1 `ul` using DOM but it doesn't work, i tried different ways still doesn't work.
I got this code so far

```
var list = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: "Dope",
        img: "pic/dope.jpg",
        link: "dope.html"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: "The Do Over",
        img: "pic/The_Do-Over.png",
        link: "The_Do-Over.html"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: "Deadpool",
        img: "pic/Deadpool.jpg",
        link: "Deadpool.html"
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        title: "Johnny English Reborn",
        img: "pic/johnny_english_reborn.jpg",
        link: "johnny_english_reborn.html"
    }
];

var input = document.getElementById("input");

for (var i = 0; i <list.length; i++) {
    var ul = document.createElement('ul');
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    var p = document.createElement('p');

    p.title = list[i].title;
    ul.appendChild(p);
    img.src = list[i].img;
    img.title = list[i].title;

    a.href = list[i].link;    
    a.appendChild(img);

    li.id = list[i].id;
    li.appendChild(a);
    ul.appendChild(li);
    console.log(ul);
    input.appendChild(ul);
};


<div id="input" >

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

These two lines can't be inside the loop. Put them above `for`:

```
var ul = document.createElement('ul');
input.appendChild(ul);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
var list = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: "Dope",
        img: "pic/dope.jpg",
        link: "dope.html"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: "The Do Over",
        img: "pic/The_Do-Over.png",
        link: "The_Do-Over.html"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: "Deadpool",
        img: "pic/Deadpool.jpg",
        link: "Deadpool.html"
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        title: "Johnny English Reborn",
        img: "pic/johnny_english_reborn.jpg",
        link: "johnny_english_reborn.html"
    }
];

var input = document.getElementById("input");

function createList() {

    var ul = document.createElement('ul');

    for (var i = 0; i <list.length; i++) {


        //create li
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.id = list[i].id;

        //create paragraph
        var p = document.createElement('p');
        p.title = list[i].title;
        li.appendChild(p);

        //create image
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = list[i].img;
        img.title = list[i].title;

        //create href
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.href = list[i].link;    
        a.appendChild(img);
        li.appendChild(a);

        //append this li to the ul
        ul.appendChild(li);

    }

    //outside the loop, append once the ul to the wrapper
    input.appendChild(ul);


};

createList();
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your expected , i have used below option which will create li of each element

```
      var list = [
          {
              id: 1,
              title: "Dope",
              img: "pic/dope.jpg",
              link: "dope.html"
          },
          {
              id: 2,
              title: "The Do Over",
              img: "pic/The_Do-Over.png",
              link: "The_Do-Over.html"
          },
          {
              id: 3,
              title: "Deadpool",
              img: "pic/Deadpool.jpg",
              link: "Deadpool.html"
          },
          {
              id: 4,
              title: "Johnny English Reborn",
              img: "pic/johnny_english_reborn.jpg",
              link: "johnny_english_reborn.html"
          }
      ];

      var input = document.getElementById("input");
      var x = Object.keys(list[0]);
      console.log(list[0][x[1]])
      for (var i = 0; i <list.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j <x.length; j++){
        console.log(list[i][x[j]])  
        var ul = document.createElement('ul');
          var li = document.createElement('li');
          var a = document.createElement("a");
          var img = document.createElement("img");
          var p = document.createElement('p');

          p.title = list[i][x[j]];
          ul.appendChild(p);
          img.src = list[i][x[j]];
          img.title = list[i][x[j]];

          a.href = list[i][x[j]];    
          a.appendChild(img);

          li.id = list[i][x[j]];
          li.appendChild(a);
          ul.appendChild(li);
          console.log(ul);
          input.appendChild(ul);
        }
      };
```

Codepen - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/GqqPOp

Answer (score 0):

Your code works in jsfiddle:

jsfiddle.net/9yq1p1zu/

Maybe,I don't get you.